# Removing coloured icons in Finder

Tags: finder, icon

There have been a number of questions for removing the muted sidebar icons and replacing them with the older coloured versions.  It's well documented that the coloured versions still happily exist and can be seen by simply looking in the Go menu of the finder app.

I want to do it the other way around.  I want to find instances of the coloured icons, and replace *those* with the muted versions instead.  The most obvious place for them to appear is in the header bar of finder windows, but there is the aforementioned go menu too.

[image: Finder Window]

How can I make all instance of a coloured finder icons for default home folder locations use the muted monochrome versions as seen in the sidebar by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [CandyBar](http://panic.com/candybar/), you can change the icons for system folders. Selecting a monochrome set of icons will make all the finder icons monochrome. Note that you cannot change the icons for applications from the App store without breaking their code signature, and thus their ability to update.

You can find the sidebar icons and most of the other icons to which you refer in the folder **/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources**

If one doesn't mind mucking about in system folders (something one should do with a great deal of caution), one might duplicate some of the Sidebar* icons and use them to replace the corresponding icons without the word Sidebar before them. I wouldn't try this without a bootable backup in place, however, in case I messed something up badly.

Comment: Will it change it in all locations, or just in the sidebar?  I like the sidebar ones best, but they are inconsistent even in the same window as per the screenshot, so there must be multiple sources?

Comment: The sidebar icon and the standard icon are two separate files. See above. And do at least visit the folder /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources even if you are too wise to mess with it.